# How to update option in react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using the react library select https://react-select.com/home, but I have a problem when updating my state and my option.

this is my function to update state regenciesOption when province changed
https://pastebin.com/iWWT8zA0

My state updates but the select option does not change and no error is reported.
Example : I change the province option, but the region option does not change.

When province changes, I am getting data region by id province (using Axios), setting state regenciesOption with response data.

In the console, `regenciesOption` was shown.

Wwhat should I do so that when I change provinces, data options in the city are also updated?

```html
<Select
   value={this.state.formKotaSelect2}
   onChange={this.onChangeSelectKota.bind(this)}
   options={this.state.regenciesOption}
   placeholder={"Pilih Kota"}
   styles={colourStyles}
/>
```

example data :

```
state regenciesOption
[
    {  value : "3601" , label : "Kabupaten Tanerang" },
    {  value : "3601" , label : "Kota Tangerang" }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Didik! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. [It works fine to update the options](https://codesandbox.io/s/llnxzx8y7q).

Comment: You have 2 Selects right? One for Province and the other one for city? Can you share them and also share the code to update your city options

Comment: share your onChange function .

Comment: this is my function to update state regenciesOption when select province changed 
https://pastebin.com/iWWT8zA0